# Xcode Swift Collision not working

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, skphysicsbody

I'm trying to get "hero" to collide with "wallGenerator" (generates walls)

but It will not collide no matter what I do. Hero will collide with the ground but not the walls as it will just run through them.

Here is the code for Hero and WallGenerator

```
    hero.position = CGPointMake(70, movingGround.position.y + movingGround.frame.size.height/2 + hero.frame.size.height/2)
    hero.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: hero.size)
    hero.physicsBody!.dynamic = true
    hero.physicsBody!.allowsRotation = false
    hero.physicsBody!.categoryBitMask = heroCategory
    hero.physicsBody!.collisionBitMask = heroCategory | wallCategory
    hero.physicsBody!.contactTestBitMask = wallCategory | heroCategory | groundCategory

    wallGenerator = CSWallGenerator(color: UIColor.clearColor(), size: view.frame.size)
    wallGenerator.position = view.center
    wallGenerator.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(edgeLoopFromRect : wallGenerator.frame)
    wallGenerator.physicsBody!.dynamic = false
    wallGenerator.physicsBody!.categoryBitMask = wallCategory
    wallGenerator.physicsBody!.collisionBitMask = wallCategory | heroCategory
```

Code for CSWallGenerator

```
class CSWallGenerator: SKSpriteNode {

var generationTimer: NSTimer?

func startGeneratingWallsEvery(seconds: NSTimeInterval) {
    generationTimer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(seconds, target: self, selector: "generateWall", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)


}

func generateWall() {
    var scale: CGFloat
    let rand = arc4random_uniform(2)
    if rand == 0 {
        scale = -1.0
    } else {
        scale = 1.0
    }

    let wall = CSWall()
    wall.position.x = size.width/2 + wall.size.width/2
    wall.position.y = scale * (kCSGroundHeight/2 + wall.size.height/2)
    addChild(wall)

}

}
```

Comment: You might want to provide some more details, such as : how you instantiate `hero`, what does `CSWallGenerator` do, how did you wrote your bitmasks (categories) ?

Comment: @lchamp I added the CSWallGenerator, also it seems to be only an issue with the wallGenerator, because my Hero can collide with my ground

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are setting the physics body for wallgenerator, but what actually gets added to scene is a cswall. Cswall doesn't have physics body set.

Try something like

```
wall.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(edgeLoopFromRect : wall.frame)
```

Inside your generateWall function

Comment: You wanted me to add that line into the CSWallGenerator file under `let wall = CSWall()
    wall.position.x = size.width/2 + wall.size.width/2
    wall.position.y = scale * (kCSGroundHeight/2 + wall.size.height/2)`

Comment: Yes, I'm not at my computer right now, so i'm not sure if the line of code is correct, but you get the idea. I think you are setting the physics body to wallgenerator and not to wall..

Comment: This worked, I had to change the code from edgeloopfromrect to rectangleOfSize to get it to work while in the cswallgenerator! Thank you for the fast response and help! :)

Comment: Cool. Good luck with your game!